# How to import a utility file into an aura component test?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, unit-test

It would be very useful to be able to import a test utils library into aura test files. For instance, a function to stub server-side responses, etc.

However, I'm not sure how to import a file (presumably from another static resource) into an aura test file.

Thanks